# what does width: 50% mean when the container is body?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, percentage

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've learned that width in percentage means the ratio compared with the container. However, when I assigned 50% to the width and height of div, I couldn't see the div. Could you please tell me why, and what the percentage here means?

Comment: You need to give the `body` and `html` 100% height for it to work

Comment: Thank you! So does the height: 100% in html mean that the height of html is 100% of the window? And what's the default height of window?

Comment: "height: 100%" means 100% of the height of the container element. Now, since the `body` has "height: auto" by default, it means it's as high as the contained `div`. But 100% of "auto" is 0. Hence the `div` has 0 height. Hence the `body` has 0 height. To solve this you need to give an explicit height to the body.

Comment: got it! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `height` fixed to work in this case, Check here

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! So could you please explain why the height is so special?

Comment: as the div inside has no content in it. for you in this case to check the width.

Comment: You need to give height for html, body. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f76gymqf/

Comment: its auto, whenever the content goes inside the div it starts flowing.

Comment: so does it mean that the browser can't calculate half the height of body if I don't assign a specific value to it?

Comment: yes. without assigning height to the parent with empty div inside it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: absolute` to the `div` and that's it!

Please learn about how the `position` works on DOM elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The percentage is calculated from the parent element, so if you set `height` you also have to set to the parent.

Comment: Thank you! But why the height is so special? Why needn't I set the width?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height : 100px;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!